# Get the name of the function from inside the function

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get the name of the function from inside the function?
Example:

```
function myFunction() {

  // console.log the name of this function without knowing/specifying what the name is
  // otherwise console.log('myFunction was called'); is 
  // more obvious (and better supported) than console.log(myFunction.name);
  // console.log(arguments.callee.name); works but not in strict mode and is deprecated
}
```

Reference:
[Function.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)
[arguments.callee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee)

**Update:**
From the comments and answers, it appears that the point has been completely missed.
I revised the example to make it clearer.

**Update 2:**
It seems there is still ambiguity ... here is an example of a debugging process:

```
function one() {
  console.log(arguments.callee.name + ' was called'); // one was called
  // reset of the code
}

function two() {
  console.log(arguments.callee.name + ' was called'); // two was called
  // reset of the code
}

function three() {
  console.log(arguments.callee.name + ' was called'); // three was called
  // reset of the code
}

function four() {
  console.log(arguments.callee.name + ' was called'); // four was called
  // reset of the code
}

function five() {
  console.log(arguments.callee.name + ' was called'); // five was called
  // reset of the code
}
```

`arguments.callee.name` is deprecated and not available in strict mode.
I am looking for a method that is not deprecated and works in strict mode.

Comment: Why can't you use `myFunction.name`?

Comment: this link will help you http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript/functions/how-to-get-function-name-from-itself.htm

Comment: console.log(myFunction.name);

Comment: also what you could do is make a "class" (and object of functions) and get the object key which would be the function name. Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)

Comment: Thank you all but the point was completely missed.

Comment: How can you define a function without knowing its name? You still don't explain why you need the name.

Comment: I use it for debugging... so it can be inserted into multiple functions so that the progress can be monitored from the console without having to manually enter each function's name .... As stated, `console.log(arguments.callee.name);` works but deprecated. I was looking for a not-deprecated option that works in strict mode. ...Nevertheless, the purpose should not matter in replying to the question

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
console.log(myFunction.name);
```

Be aware that this is not supported by IE yet as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)

Comment: Thank you but the point was completely missed. I made some clarifications.